# How to deselect all DataGrid rows in code using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a view with a dataGrid and the ViewModel. I want that when some condition occurs, deselect all the rows selected.

With Windows.Interactivity I can covert an event into a command, so with the event selectedChanged of the dataGrid. Then I check the conditions, and I can set the SelectedIndex to -1 if I want to deselect the items, nut this only works if I have only one item selected, if I have more than one, It does not work.

How can I deselect all the rows selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IsSelected` property of the rows should be bound to your VM anyway, so you should be able to iterate over the items and set it to `false`.

Comment: How can I bound the properties of a row? I am starting with MVVM and I know how to bound the properties of the dataGrid, but not of the elements of the dataGrid.


Thanks.

Comment: @Daimroc: You can use the [`DataGrid.RowStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowstyle.aspx) for that.